# Sending E-mail to Multiple Recipients with Authentication

Tags: email, powershell

I am trying to send an e-mail through Powershell. I can send e-mails to one recipient without a problem using the code below. However, when I add a second recipient to the `$EmailTo` variable, I do not get the e-mail. I do not get any errors either. I did some research and it appears that the SMTP Client way of sending e-mails does not take multiple recipients.

```psh
$EmailFrom = "sender@email.com" 
$EmailTo = "recipient1@email.com"
$EmailBody = "Test Body" 
$EmailSubject = "Test Subject"
$Username = "carlos@email.com"
$Password = "12345"

$Message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $EmailSubject, $EmailBody)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.com", 123) #Port can be changed 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$SMTPClient.Send($Message)
```

I tried with the `Send-MailMessage` command but it is giving me issues.

```psh
Send-MailMessage -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject `
  -smtpserver smtp.com -usessl `
  -credential (new-object System.NetworkCredential("$Username","$Password"))
```

The error I get with this is

> Cannot find type [System.NetworkCredential]...

Any ideas on what the best way to send emails to multiple recipients with authentication would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you separate your `$EmailTo` address list with commas and don't pass as an array. i.e:

**Do this:**

```
$EmailTo = "recipient1@email.com,recipient2@email.com"
```

***Don't* do this:**

```
$EmailTo = "recipient1@email.com","recipient2@email.com"
```

or this:

```
$EmailTo = "recipient1@email.com;recipient2@email.com"
```

That last one would throw the following exception which you'd easily notice:

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "4" argument(s): "The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address."

Answer (score 0):

The class name is [`System.Net.NetworkCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not `System.NetworkCredential`.

Change this:

```psh
Send-MailMessage -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject `
  -smtpserver smtp.com -usessl `
  -credential (new-object System.NetworkCredential("$Username","$Password"))
```

into this:

```psh
Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject `
  -SmtpServer smtp.com -UseSsl `
  -Credential (New-Object Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password))
```

and the problem should disappear.